# Why are there extraneous brackets in my Firefox dialogs?

Tags: firefox, gui, dialog

For approximately two months (after an upgrade to version ~45) my Firefox dialogs have had extraneous brackets (see diagram). This happens on both Windows and Ubuntu. Is this a Firefox bug, a change in the Firefox API that I need to report to plugin authors, or something else?

[image: log in (brackets) or cancel (brackets)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've [reported](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1362960) such a problem with Firefox 53 HU. It's caused by invalid access key configuration. Mostly in localized files, I guess. It's a Mozilla bug, so you should report it in their Bugzilla if it comes up again.